# Why div is not vertically center with transform3d inside flex-holder in chrome browser?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

In the below snippet I have a yellow color child div. And also, it's inside a flex holder. When I try to vertically center it using below css

`transform:translate3d(0,-50%,0); position:relative; top:50%`

it's not getting center aligned in chrome browser. Any idea why it's not vertically center aligned. But it's centered in other browsers. Currently my chrome browser version is `Version 84.0.4147.105`

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.box {
  border-color: blue;
}

.parent{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border-color: green;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-holder">
  <div class="box">
    BOX
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
        CENTER
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    BOX
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the issue is related to top:50%

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.box {
  border-color: blue;
}

.parent{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border-color: green;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-holder">
  <div class="box">
    BOX
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
        CENTER
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    BOX
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Made change to your child class.